# What is the bijection in this combinatorics example?

Tags: combinatorics

> **Example 3.19.** A medical student has to work in a hospital for five
>   days in January. However, he is not allowed to work two consecutive
>   days in the hospital. In how many different ways can he choose the
>   five days he will work in the hospital?
>
> **Solution.** The difficulty here is to make sure that we do not choose
>   two consecutive days. This can be assured by the following trick. Let
>   $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$, $a_4$, $a_5$ be the dates of the five days of January that the
>   student will spend in the hospital, in increasing order. Note that the
>   requirement that there are no two consecutive numbers among the $a_i$,
>   and $1 \le a_i \le 31$ for all $i$ is equivalent to the requirement that 
>   $1 \le a_1 \lt a_2 - 1 \lt a_3 - 2 \lt a_4 - 3 \lt a_5 - 4 \le 27$. In other words, 
>   there is
>   an obvious bijection between the set of 5-element subsets of $[31]$
>   containing no two consecutive elements and the set of 5-element
>   subsets of [27]. Instead of choosing the numbers $a_i$, we can choose the
>   numbers $1 \le a_1 \lt a_2 - 1 \lt a_3 - 2 \lt a_4 - 3 \lt a_5 - 4 \le 27$, that is, we
>   can simply choose a five-element subset of $[27]$, and we know that
>   there are $27 \choose 5$ ways to do that.

Note: the bracket notation $[27]$ means $\{1,2,3,...27\}$.

Was reading this example from *A Walkthrough Combinatorics* (Bona), but I'm not really sure I follow what the "obvious bijection" is suppose to be.  Does this mean that if I choose a random five-element subset of $[27]$ say: $\{1,7,27,25,6\}$ then ordered it from least to greatest: $\{1,6,7,25,27\}$ then to map to the actual days (the five-element subset of $[31]$) I would compute:

$\{1+0, 6+1, 7+2, 25+3, 27+4\} = \{1, 7, 9, 28, 31\}$ So the bijection (to map from a five element set of [27]) is to add 0,1,2,3,4 to that ordered set? (Sorry not really sure how to express this in more mathematical notation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following does not precisely answer your bijection question, but it gives what we believe is a quick way to **see** what the answer is.

There will be $26$ non-work days. To represent them, put $26$ $\times$ (or perhaps beer bottles) in a row, somewhat separated from each other, like this:
$$\times\quad\times \quad\times\quad\times\quad \times\quad\times \quad\times\quad \dots\dots \quad\times\quad\times\quad\times \quad\times$$
These determine $27$ "gaps." We are including the two invisible endgaps.

We need to **choose** $5$ of these gaps as workdays.

**Remark:** If one really wants to use the word, there is a *bijection* from the set of workday choices to the set of choices of $5$ gaps: once we know the workdays, we will know which gaps were chosen and vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks your use of the X's and gaps really helped me see this.

Comment: As I thought more on it, I think the bijection would be $f(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5) = (a_1,a_2+1,a_3+2,a_4+3,a_5+4)$ To go from say gap numbers to day numbers.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, you advance by $1$ each time. And of course the idea generalizes.

Comment: I was still pondering this question, and I think I understand better the "invisible" endgaps.  Those are the start/end of some other Months (e.g. Dec & Feb) so that's why we include them.  Had Jan wrapped around on itself then one end gap would be lost.

Comment: There is a difference of treatment, albeit not a very large one, between ordinary permutations and the "circular" permutations, precisely because of the "wraparound."